# My laptop cant detect my nexus7

Tags: nexus-7, tablet, usb-connection-mode

My laptop used to detect my nexus7 tablet but for some reason its stopped detecting it. Any way to try and get it to start detecting it again?

Comment: Well, did you tried restarting your device?? I would say better to try restarting your device as well as the PC you are trying to connect it with and do make sure that you have selected MTP mode and if that still doesn't helps then try removing the USB cable and try reconnecting it !

Answer (score 0):

These can be a little tricky to troubleshoot without a LOT more information and a ton of back and forth. My best suggestion to do an end-run around all of that would be for you to download [WugFresh's Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/).

Now don't worry if you're not interested in rooting, as that's not why I'm suggesting it. I've just found that its "Full Driver Installation - Automatic + Manual" function is one of the easiest, cleanest, most step-by-step ways to both clean out all the remnants of the old Nexus drivers that might be causing your problem, and installing the most appropriate new drivers that will hopefully resolve your problem the rest of the way. A bunch of them are for the purpose of flashing/rooting/repairing/etc., but even if you don't want that, it can't hurt to have them there in case you have a need for that later.

Outside of that, a few main suggestions that sound obvious, but assuming they can't be the case sometimes bites us in the butt:

1. Try a different cable. Even when the cable charges fine, or connects for some purposes all right, it can end up causing issues in other situations. Worth a shot.
2. Try a different port. Any different port, but especially if you're connecting via a USB 3.0 port, try a 2.0 port. There are some known, odd issues with Nexus devices and some USB 3.0 controllers.
3. Try switching the connection method. When you connect it, there should be a notification allowing you to switch connection modes. One usually works better than the other in some situations.
4. Try it in a different computer to verify there isn't a problem with the port on the Nexus 7 itself.

That's about all I've got. Good luck!